# prove property of the definite integral of a function of sine.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Show that 
$$\int_0^{\pi}x\;f(\sin x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}f(\sin x)dx$$
I tried to prove this using integration by parts and u-subs but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Use  $\displaystyle I=\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$

and $\displaystyle\sin(\pi+0-x)=\sin x$

So, $\displaystyle I+I=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b\left[f(x)+f(a+b-x)\right]dx$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi}x\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
&=
\half\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi}x\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+
\int_{0}^{\pi}\pars{\pi - x}\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{\pi - x}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi}x\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+
\int_{0}^{\pi}\pars{\pi - x}\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=
\color{#00f}{\large{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\fermi\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}