Prove that $\int_0^\pi {x\,f(\sin x)\,} dx = \frac{\pi }{2}\int_0^\pi {f(\sin x)} \,dx$
It is also given that $f$ is a continuous function.
Specifically, the question tasks to use the substitution $x=\pi - t$. However, I don't seem to be able to get anything useful out of this substitution:
$$ \begin{align}  \int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx&=\int_\pi^0 (\pi -t)f(\sin (\pi - t)) (-dt)\\&=-\int_\pi^0 (\pi -t)f(\sin (t))dt\\&=\int_0^\pi (\pi -t)f(\sin (t))dt \end{align} $$
Then:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi (\pi -t)f(\sin (t))dt&=\int_0^\pi \pi f(\sin (t))dt - \int_0^\pi tf(\sin (t))dt\\&=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin (t))dt - \int_0^\pi tf(\sin (t))dt \end{align} $$
However here is where I'm lost. By putting back $t=\pi-x$ I'm just reversing the process which puts me right back where I started, leaving me with no clue on how to continue. I also tried to use integration by parts on the last result, but it didn't look like it would yield anything of value.

My gut is telling me that I should be able to somehow get something in the lines of:
$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin (x))dx - \int_0^\pi xf(\sin (x))dx$
then I would move $\int_0^\pi xf(\sin (x))dx$ to the other side and get the desired result. But I'm stuck with the substituted $t$ variable instead.
Any hints would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

NOTE: I've seen other answers which use:
$\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=\int_0^\pi f(0+\pi-x)dx$
but the question specifically asks to use $x=\pi - t$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639443/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/971888/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3986712/42969

Thanks Martin, but as I've said I've already peeked at some of the answers and saw them using the formula I specified at the bottom of the post. The question specifically asks to use $x=\pi - t$. Maybe I'm missing the connection between the two.

Your hunch is absolutely right in how you derive the identity. Just because the variable of integration is labelled as $t$ instead of $x$ doesn't mean that the integrals are not equal. It's the same integrand over the same bounds.

$\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=\int_0^\pi f(0+\pi-x)dx$ is the substitution $x=\pi -t $, then renaming $t$ to $x$.

Note that $$\int_a^b f(x),dx=\int_a^b f(t),dt=\int_a^b f(u),du=\int_a^b f(\text{anything}),d,\text{anything}$$

@MarkViola thanks for the comment. But how can both of the integrals in your comment be equal when $x=\pi - t$?

To @MarkViola's point, take a look at How do I convince my students that the choice of variable of integration is irrelevant?

On one hand it is obvious to me that the equalities mentioned in @MarkViola 's comment are correct. I understand them. I don't understand how the equality $\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx = \int_0^\pi tf(\sin t)dt$ is correct, if I previously substituted $x=\pi-t$...

There are solutions in the links provided in the comments, although I prefer the following. The function $tf(\cos t)$ for $|t|\le \pi/2$ is odd therefore its integral over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ vanishes. Substitution $t=x-\pi/2$ gives $$\int\limits_0^\pi (x-\pi/2)f(\sin x),dx =0$$ and the conclusion follows.

@EmanuelL In my comment,  let that function $f(x)$ be your function $xf(x)$.  You see, the variable that appears under the definite integral is a "dummy" variable.  It is a symbol only.  One may replace any one symbol with any other symbol and the value of the integral is unaffected.

Hint: Let $I=\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx$. Then after the substitution $t=\pi-x$, you get
$$I=\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\,dx-\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)\,dx=\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\,dx-I.$$
Now solve for $I$!

This will probably sound dumb, but where did $t$ go to?

Is that solution different from those in the three Q&As that I linked to in my first comment?

Sorry Martin, the solution may be apparent to you, and in your eyes this answer is probably identical to all others. I did follow the links, read the answers and followed the advised links in the comments. I would elaborate about what I don't understand in those links, but I think it would be too long for a comment.
